# Save payment with non-default method

Tags: magento

I use code to create a checkout and I would like to set a payment method for this checkout. I would like to use ccsave, but it gives me an error the expiration date is missing for the request.

My code:

```
$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
$checkout->initCheckout();
$checkout->saveCheckoutMethod('register');
$checkout->saveShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
$checkout->savePayment(array('method' => 'ccsave'));

try {
    $checkout->saveOrder();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

How to set the expiration date and other required parameters for the payment method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$checkout->savePayment(array(
    'method' => 'ccsave', 
    'cc_owner' => 'ffffffffff', 
    'cc_type' => 'VI', 
    'cc_number' => '4111111111111111', 
    'cc_exp_year' => 2015, 
    'cc_exp_month' => 11,
    'cc_cid' => 123
));
```